# Invocation of a REST method with AsyncTask every 10 seconds in Android

Tags: android

I need to invoke a REST method of the server every 10 seconds,

and my intention was to use an AsyncTask to do it in the following way:

```
myTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    ...
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //invoke REST service
        ....
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        //post execute operations
        ...
    }
};
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the solution is invoke AsyncTask from a TimerTask

```
protected class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        (new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                ...
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                //invoke REST service
                ....
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
                super.onPostExecute(response);
                //post execute operations
                ...
            }
        }).execute();
    }
}
```

if you are afraid that the invocation to the server takes too long and then demands that they overlap, you can enter a semaphore with a AtomicBoolean (synchronized) in the following way:

semaphore declaration

```
private final AtomicBoolean isRunning = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

TimerTask with a semaphore

```
protected class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //if isRunning is true does not execute the task
        if (isRunning.get()) return;

        (new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                //active flag isRunning
                isRunning.set(true);

                ...
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                ....
                //invoke REST service
                ....
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
                super.onPostExecute(response);
                //post execute operations
                ...

                //deactive flag isRunning
                isRunning.set(false);
            }
        }).execute();
    }
}
```

note: careful to turn off the semaphore when you catch a error, because if for some reason remains active will no longer run the AsyncTask

Answer (score 2):

Consider using AlarmManager.  Create a service or a broadcast receiver to catch the AlarmManager intent and make your server request.  Below example illustrates how to establish repeating events every 10 seconds from AlarmManager.

```
   AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
   PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);
   am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), TEN_SECONDS, pending);
```